# Actualizar tabla en template desde el back end

Tags: python-3.x, json, django, opencv

**Hola, estoy comenzando a utilizar JSON en mi proyecto DJANGO, mi proyecto es sobre reconcimiento facial por lo que uso una etiqueta IMG para Streaming, lo que necesito hacer es que al reconocer el rostro, el nombre obtenido quiero mostrarlo en una tabla en el template, de momento he estado inventado pero no logro. Alguien pudiera asesorarme porfavor se lo agradeceria**

> Archivo reconocimiento.py
> **Este archivo es el nucleo del proceso de reconcimiento, y es llamado en el metodo "marcacionfacial" en el archivo vistas, intentando lograrlo declare una lista "marcaciones", donde se guardan los nombres de los reconocidos, y esta lista la importo en el archivo vistas**

```
marcaciones=[] 
class Reconocimientofacial(object):
.....


   def reconofacial(self):
 if result[1] < 80:
                    if len(imagePaths)-1 <= result[0]:
                        cv2.putText(frame, '{}'.format(imagePaths[result[0]]), (x, y-25), 2, 1.1, (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                        #cv2.putText(frame, 'nombre', (x+150, y-25), 2,0.8, (255, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        # obteniendo el nombre del reconocido para uso de BD
                        # carnet = print(imagePaths[result[0]])
                        
     #  Este marcaciones es una lista global, y es lo que necesito que se muestre en el template
                        marcaciones.append({'nombre':imagePaths[result[0]]})
                else:
                    cv2.putText(frame, 'Desconocido', (x, y-20), 2,0.8, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

> archivo vistas.py

**En este archivo tengo los dos metodos principales para el streaming de video, marcacionfacial y gen2, el metodo marcacionhtml me funciona al llamarlo desde el template por medio de ajax y he puesto de prueba un array (aqui no lo muestro), ya tengo la url condigurado y me responde, pero no se como utilizarlo para que lo que venga del metodo reconofacial() del archivo reconocimiento.py

En este archivo vistas intente importando la lista marcaciones, la comparo con la lista local marcaciones2 si hay diferencias enviar la actualizacion al template, pero es un intento divagando...
**

```
from IAG4USAM.modulos.ReconocimientoFacial import Reconocimientofacial,marcaciones

marcaciones2 = []
#funciones para modulo de reconicimiento facial
def gen2(camreconcimiento):
    while True:
        frame = camreconcimiento.reconofacial()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


def marcacionfacial(request):
    if not comparar_listas(marcaciones2,marcaciones):
        #si la lista cambia de elementos se envia el cambio a la tabla
        marcacionhtml(request)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen2(Reconocimientofacial()),
                  content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def marcacionhtml(request):
    #devuelve en JSON
    datos = marcaciones
    return JsonResponse(datos,safe=False)


def comparar_listas(a,b):
    return Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

> Archivo Template

**Este es el codigo del template, tengo la etiqueta IMG donde observo el video, y la tabla que deseo actualizar, la url mostrarmarcaciones es la que apunta al metodo "marcacionhtml" de la vistas.py**

```
    <body>
 <h1>Marcacion</h1>
 <img src="{% url 'marcacionfacial' %}"> 
<table>
<tr>
<th>marcacion</th>
</tr>
<tbody id="tabla1">
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</head>
</html>


<script>

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: {% url 'mostrarmarcaciones' %},
    success: function(response){
        datosarray = response;
        
        llenartabla(datosarray);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log("error de json");
        console.log(error);
    }
});



function llenartabla(data){
    var nomtabla = document.getElementById('tabla1')
    for (var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
        var row = `<tr>
                   <td>${data[i].nombres}<td>
                   <tr>`
        nomtabla.innerHTML += row
    }
}

</script>
```